# IIS 10 hidden segments go to 404 page instead of 400 which I am setting in URL Rewrite rule

Tags: rewrite, iis-10

I have a URL Rewrite rule to prevent accessing the site from any URL except a defined list. The rule returns `400 Bad Request` if the URL is not in the list.

```
    <rule name="No unknown hosts" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^admin\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="400" />
    </rule>
```

Examples of URLs I'm trying to block are `mail.example.com` or `102.15.63.233`. This works great, *except* when a hidden segment is appended to the URL, like so `mail.example.com/bin/`. This goes to my custom 404 error page, which among other things looks like crap because all of the style sheets and other assets (images, etc.) won't resolve since the URL is blocked and returning 400. Worse than that, it triggers an error in PCI DSS scans because they think I'm allowing directory browsing.

I've spent almost the whole day doing Google searches every possible way I can think of with no success. Oh, the reason for doing it this way is so that an invalid HOST header cannot be used to trick our site into redirecting to a malicious site (many other Rewrite rules rely on that functionality). I'm hoping someone here has an answer.

Comment: By default URL rewrite module in IIS takes highest priority to execute, so that 404 cannot happen. You will have to enable FRT to learn more about that 404, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules as someone might misconfigure IIS in the past.

Comment: @LexLi FRT shows the 404 error is generated before it hits any of the URL Rewrite rules. In fact, after that error is generated, no attempt is made to even look at the Inbound URL Rewrite rules.

Comment: Which module generated the 404 response? Like I commented earlier, ULR Rewrite module should be the first to respond, so very likely there is some misconfiguration.